# python json unhashable type 'list'

Tags: python, linux

I have this code which submits the JSON data to the server, however it gives the error "unhashable type list"

```
hcatalog_nodes =["idh30-1.srv.acent.net.uk","idh30-2.srv.acent.net.uk","idh30-3.srv.acent.net.uk"]
for node in hcatalog_nodes:
    data = json.dumps({[
                            {
                                "rolename": "HCatalog",
                                "hostname": node
                            }

                        ]})
    request = urllib2.Request("https://192.168.0.76:9443/restapi/acent/api/v2/cluster/"+cluster_name+"/services/hbase/roles")
    base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % ("admin", "admin")).replace('\n', '')
    request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
    print "setting up HBase roles on node %s " % (node)
    result = urllib2.urlopen(request,data)
    print result.read()
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kshk/PycharmProjects/intelIDH/autoIDH.py", line 287, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/kshk/PycharmProjects/intelIDH/autoIDH.py", line 278, in main
    add_hcatalogRoles()
  File "/home/kshk/PycharmProjects/intelIDH/autoIDH.py", line 147, in add_hcatalogRoles
    "hostname": node
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

any ideas how i can set the value of "node" in the json request?

Comment: You're problem is not with JSON serialization, is already with defining a valid Python data structure. You're trying to dump `{[...` - that's a set with a **list** as one of its elements. Set elements can only be hashable types. A list is not hashable, therefore the error.

Comment: @LukasGraf: I think you mean "set" and "element" where you've written "dictionary" and "key".

Comment: @DSM err, you're obviously right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is on the `json.dumps()` line:

```
data = json.dumps({[{"rolename": "HCatalog", "hostname": node}]})
```

This basically tries to create a set with only one list element. Python list cannot be an element of a set.

---

You probably wanted to create a dictionary instead and pass it to `json.dumps()`:

```
data = json.dumps({"rolename": "HCatalog", "hostname": node})
```

Comment: OK, how do i set the value of node?

Comment: You just have an extraneous set of curly braces that represents a set-literal which can not contain a list. Remove the outermost ones.

Comment: that gives me another error "unhashable type: dict"

Comment: Use what alexce posted.